# Google dialogflow Locale and language

Tags: language, locale

I am using dialogflow to create a Chatbot in ZH-ch. When I tried to integrate it via google assistant, I got the following error message:

> Request contains an invalid argument. Locale zh-CN was selected but the language zh has not been selected.

And also on the google action simulator, only ZH-tw is an option to choose?